# How to show dialog on start of subscribe?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I want to show ProgressBar while performing of Observable:

```
Observable<T> observable;
Observer<T> observer;
...................
observable.doOnSubscribe(()->{showProgressBar();}
          .finallyDo(()-> {hideProgressBar();})
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(observer);

...................
    protected void showProgressBar() {
        if (mProgressBar != null)
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    protected void hideProgressBar() {
        if (mProgressBar != null)
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

;

but I receive this error:

```
 android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

on line   `mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

**how to run `showProgressBar()` from `doOnSubscribe()`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
          .doOnSubscribe(()->{showProgressBar();}
          .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .finallyDo(()-> {hideProgressBar();})        
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

should work. The side effect operators execute synchronously on whatever thread calls it so just work backwards. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/zsxwing/a82d9e477b04ec64e6df) and [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rxjava/TCGBiT0gbyI).